# Allow manual entry on list data validation when sheet is protected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has some cells that have a list type data validation with "Show error alert..." unchecked so that  you can still manually type an option that might not be in the list. this works when the sheet is not protected, but when it is, and the cell is unlocked, it no longer allows manually typing anything while the normal selection from the list works fine. I use the following code to protect the sheet whenever it is opened.

```
Private Sub WorkBook_Activate()
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub
```

When I manually protect the sheet (unprotect it then protect it myself in the review tab) I can select "Edit Objects" and that does exactly what I want. The only results that come up when trying to figure out how to do that with VBA use DrawingObjects:=False when protecting it.
I have already tried using

```
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False
```

but this for whatever reason does not protect the sheet at all. Is this the wrong approach? What's going on?

Comment: Hmm. I can't seem to replicate the problem. I ran the same code and I'm able to edit with the dropdown or by typing.

Comment: is the rest of the sheet still protected too? @BryanRock

Comment: Yes. I can't select or edit anything other than the unlocked cells with data validation.

Comment: ok Let me try to recreat it in a new workbook. Maybe my problem is somewhere else

Comment: Yea I can't seem to recreate it myself and for whatever reason it is now working in my main worksheet as well even though I didn't change anything. So this was seemingly a pointless post.

Comment: Well actually, when I add the ", DrawingObjects:=False" to that line, it breaks the protection still, even though I don't need it since it works fine without it. So I'm not sure why that breaks it. Is it worth mentioning that this is put in the "ThisWorkbook" page?

Comment: I figured given the `Workbook_Activate` part. As for `DrawingObjects:=FALSE`, not sure why it would cause any problems, but unless you have objects you need to be able to edit, there's no reason to depart from the default (`DrawingObjects=TRUE`.)

Comment: Did you try moving this code to a different event, such as Workbook_Open/Worksheet_Activate? While testing the Workbook_Activate didn't seem to get triggered reliably unless you're switching between differrent workbooks. Also, while testing at least, it could help to first do an Activesheet.Unprotect() before protecting the sheet the way you want, to exclude any lingering protections with the wrong settings from remaining enabled and thus throwing you off.

Comment: @Slaqr It was my coworkers that had told me that they couldn't type anything and could only use the list options. I tried myself and also found the same problem. I think I found what was happening though. When you have the list open to select something, it won't let you type so you have to click the cell again closing the list and then type. It was probably just a dumb error like that I hadn't thought about before. The unprotect first is a good idea though. Ill throw it in there just to be sure.